# Mouse scrolling is not work in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, xhtml

I used this code to navigate a form in a webpage.but this code only works for the chrome browser and not firefox.so How can I work in firefox too ..

```
$('#swapScorell1').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {

    $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() - e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY);
    event.cancelBubble = true;

    //prevent page fom scrolling
    return false;

});
```

"swapScorell1" is id of the div tag form

Answer (score 1):

`mousewheel` event does not work in firefox.

use `DOMMouseScroll`.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml

Answer (score 0):

**FireFox does not support mousewheel. So can do the following.**

var mousewheelevent=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"

To calculate scroll in FF you need e.originalEvent.detail > 0
In others you need e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0